# Oracle 10g and Problem on Vista with visual studio 2010 installation

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2010, windows-vista, oracle10g, database-connection

I am havng the following problem after installing oracle 10g on vista machine and running an asp.net application.
Rather strange: One 2010 project on the same machine using the same database is able to work but the other that was converted to 2010 recently isnt working on the same machine.

The error is :

OCIEnvCreate failed with return code -1 but error message text was not available.

Any run into same issue with possible solutions ?

Thanks.

Comment: Insufficient information. 32-bit or 64-bit. Which version/edition/patchset of Windows ? Is this a client or server installation ? Is there a database ? Can you connect to it with SQL*Plus....

Answer (score 0):

As a colleague of mine found out, you must give to your user full rights over the oracle folder and also you must run vs 2010 in compatibility mode.

Answer (score -1):

We have full rights for it.

I also read the disadvantages of running in compatibility mode:
Refer: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaronru/archive/2009/06/09/please-do-not-install-visual-studio-2010-in-compatibility-mode.aspx

So that may not be the best solution.

Comment: SO is not a forum so treat it as such.  You should either edit your  question with this additional information or comment directly on the response you're replaying to.  Obviously it would be easier if you were using a single registered user account instead of multiple unregistered ones.

Comment: I did NOT say you should install Visual Studio 2010 in compatibility mode. I did say you should run Visual Studio 2010 in compatibility mode, i.e. when you execute devenv.exe, you execute it in compatibility mode.